# Windows DNS configurations for outside IP

Tags: apache-2.2, windows, domain-name-system, internal-dns, godaddy

Here is my problem.

I have a Windows DNS that points to 5 servers all within the LAN.  Locally the routing to these servers works fine but I need a way to access these servers outside the LAN ( HTTP ).

The DNS has an outside IP, is it possible to point my domain names for these 5 servers ( I bought them on Go Daddy ) to the DNS outside  IP and the DNS will route the traffic accordingly?

The reason is so I don't need an outside IP for each server but can use one outside IP?

www.server1.com -> DNS ( outside IP ) -> internal server1
www.server2.com -> DNS ( outside IP ) -> internal server2
www.server3.com -> DNS ( outside IP ) -> internal server3
www.server4.com -> DNS ( outside IP ) -> internal server4
www.server5.com -> DNS ( outside IP ) -> internal server5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, because:

> and the DNS will route the traffic accordingly?

DNS does not route. Never. DNS answers "where is this domain" with an IP.

What you ask for is basically a reverse IP NAT; check your firewall / router documentation.

Comment: Question doesnt the Forward Look Up Zones & Reverse Lookup Zones handle this routing?

Comment: Ah, no. See, DNS is like a phone book. It does not care aboout routing. As in: DOES NOT CARE. It returns an IP address. Basic Network Administrator knowledge.

Comment: ok thanks.  I am no network admin just a programmer poking around where apparently I shouldn't be :)

Comment: Actually your network guy should set this up. Reverse NAT - mapping outside IP traffic to internal servers - is similar complexity of boiling an egg for a cook. The DNS then points to the external IP and the router forwards the traffic - but that needs some knowledge of IP to set it up.

Comment: *Tongue in cheek* but isn't forwarding kinda' like routing? ;)

Comment: No as in this case the packets have to be rewritten to hide the origin.